# Unable to open database remotely

Tags: asp.net

Pls help me, My newly created web application is using a SQLServer Express database. If I run the application in local machine its working fine, but if I try to open the database connection from another system in the network it is giving error **Cannot open database** . I have used connection string --

conn.ConnectionString = "integrated security=SSPI;data source=USER-CCE8C22332\SQLEXPRESS;" +"persist security info=False;initial catalog=Marketee";

Comment: You will have to check with your network administrator - the connection string is trying to connect to `USER-CCE8C22332`, probably using the default 1433 port.

Comment: Could you post your exact error so that we can assist you?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to give access to the ASPNET user to access your database if you are using integrated security.  The reason is that when the user connects to the website, the server-side processing is done via the user set up in IIS in teh application pool.

To test, what you can do is switch from integrated security to passing a username and login and see if you can connect then.